# What's the best way to schedule a Scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, scheduled-tasks, worker

I need my spider to run every minute. Usually for scheduling tasks I use celery-beat, however, from what I've read, Celery is not used with scrapy.

What's the best approach to schedule scrapy spiders?

Answer (score 0):

[Zyte's Scrapy Cloud](https://www.zyte.com/scrapy-cloud/) works seamlessly with Scrapy and has a feature for scheduling periodic jobs.

Another option, if you're using any Unix-like, would be [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday);
  * * * * * scrapy crawl my_spider
```